# How open FireFox from terminal with firebug enabled?

Tags: linux, firefox, terminal, firebug

Want to open firefox from terminal at linux with firebug enabled

```
// Terminal 
$ Firefox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xdotool`:

```
#!/bin/bash
wid=$(xdotool search 'mozilla firefox' | head -1)
xdotool windowactivate $wid
xdotool key F12
```